# How to remove a plus when clicking on a phone number?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

How to remove a plus when clicking on a phone number?

Now I have a link with a phone number and when I click on it, the system itself substitutes a plus, how to get rid of it?

```
<a href={`tel:08001999`} /> // My number
```

When pressed, the phone opens a call with the following number:

```
+08001999
```

And how to do with this?

```
08001999
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the country code along with your number and the number should still work with the plus too.

E.g. if your country code is say, `91`, then your anchor href would look like this:

```
<a href={`tel:9108001999`} />
```

And the phone would open a call with the following number which should work fine:

```
+9108001999
```